# How to connect 1 domain to 2 different websites

Tags: html, css, mobile, device

I coded myself into an issue I knew I was getting into from the start.  I was under a pretty tight time constraint, and my scope of knowledge on this was basically 'learn as I go.'  I had to create a simple desktop portfolio site with simple mobile viewing.  So skipping the process ahead, I am at the point where I have a desktop site with its own selectors, names, IDs, extended markup, forms, etc... and a mobile site with different IDs, selectors, less markup, bootstrap mobility, less javascript, etc..  Both work just fine on their own.

The problem is, I need the user device to be recognized as mobile and run the separate mobile site once detected, and when recognized as desktop run the desktop site once detected.

Is there a catch in the tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

I can write that will automatically toggle the site that is needed to run?  I am used to running conditionals in CSS on queries and changing CSS, but since my syntax and markup is all different for both, that's really not an option to go back to.

Also, can I just check the device-width, run the @media query and point to a http://m.example.com where example is the root for all components in my mobile project?  Thanks so much for any kind of help/information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use php to redirect your users to the mobile site.

```
$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry == true) 
{ 
   echo "<script>window.location='http://m.site.com'</script>";
}
```

Or you can use javascript to redirect your users:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 699) {
document.location = "mobile.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

And yes you could also use media querys
Maybe you should also take a look at Bootstrap for the next project.
Bootstrap is an easy way to make your website responsive for all screen sizes.

Put your javascript at the end of your code like this:

```
<html>
</head></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    if (screen.width <= 699) {
    document.location = "mobile.html";
    }
    //-->
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

change the number of 699 to the width you want to have users redirected with.
for example if with is 900 all users with a screen width of 900 will be redirected etc.

If you want a more precise code that will redirect all phone and tablet users then use this code:

```
(function(a,b){if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))window.location=b})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera,'http://www.m.yoursite.com');
```

Comment: Many thanks!  Where would I place the javascript?  In the head of my index and redirect it to index_mobile.html?

Comment: No put the javascript code at the end of your website. Because your website will then load a little faster. So put it before the end of your end body tag. and yes replace mobile.html to http://www.m.yoursite.com

Comment: If this then helped then tick my answer as the answer to the question. So people will know its the right answer and it might help them aswell.